# Decomposition of polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{gl}_n]$ as a $\mathfrak{gl}_n$-module

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am quite sure that this is written somewhere in the literature but I could not find a reference.

Let $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ be the Lie algebra of (complex) $n\times n$ matrices and let $E_{ij}$ be the standard basis of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ consisting of matrix units. In particular, they satisfy the following  Lie algebra structure is given by the following commutation relations:
$$
[E_{ij},E_{kl}]=\delta_{jk}E_{il}-\delta_{li}E_{kj},~\text{for all}~i,j,k,l\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\},
$$
where $\delta_{\alpha\beta}$ is the Kronecker delta.

Now, consider the coordinate ring $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{gl}_n]\simeq\mathfrak{gl}_n^*$. This ring is just a polynomial ring in $n^2$ variables $(x_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{n}$, which correspond to the $(i,j)$-entry of a matrix in $\mathfrak{gl}_n$.

Next, it is known that the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{gl}_n)$ has a faithful representation in the space of the differential operators in variables $x_{ij}$ with polynomial coefficients. Namely, the corresponding map $L$ sends $E_{ij}$ to
$$
L(E_{ij})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{ik}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{jk}}.
$$
In particular, this gives a representation of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ (or $U(\mathfrak{gl}_n)$) on the space $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{gl}_n]$.

> **Question.** Is it known how does the representation $(L,\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{gl}_n])$ decompose into the irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$?

I am interested in the explicit description of these subrepresentations inside $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{gl}_n]$, but this might be not too realistic. It would be nice to have at least the description of all occuring highest weights.

**Some general ideas:** one can check that the described action of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ preserves many gradings. To be more precise, for all $i,j,k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ the operator $L(E_{ij})$ preserves the total degree in variables that appear in $k$-th row (or column). This already gives some non-trivial decomposition of $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{gl}_n]$.

Comment: I initially thought that this should be known, so posted it on MSE, but perhaps it is actually more appropriate to (cross-)post this on MO.

Comment: This action preserves the grading, so its $k$-th component is an action of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ on the $k$-th symmetric power $S^k\left(\mathfrak{gl}_n^\ast\right)$. But your action is also an action by derivations, so that this action is just the usual $k$-th symmetric power of the adjoint $\mathfrak{gl}_n$-module $\mathfrak{gl}_n$. Thus, I believe what you are asking is equivalent to computing the plethysm $h_k\left[f\right]$, where $f = h_1 h_1^-$ is the character of the adjoint $\mathfrak{gl}_n$-module $\mathfrak{gl}_n$. But I don't know if there is a known answer to this.

Comment: (Here I use the notation $h_1^-$ for $h_1\left(\dfrac{1}{x_1},\dfrac{1}{x_2},\ldots,\dfrac{1}{x_n}\right)$.)

Comment: Actually, this may not be that hard. We have $h_k\left[f\right] = h_k\left[h_1h_1^-\right] = h_k\left(x_1x_1^{-1},\ x_1x_2^{-1},\ \ldots,\ x_nx_n^{-1}\right)$, where on the right hand side we are plugging all the $n^2$ products $x_ix_j^{-1}$ into $h_k$. But Cauchy's formula yields $h_k\left(x_1y_1,\ x_1y_2,\ \ldots,\ x_ny_n\right) = \sum\limits_{\lambda\vdash k} s_\lambda\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\right) s_\lambda\left(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n\right)$. Thus, ...

Comment: ... we get $h_k\left(x_1x_1^{-1},\ x_1x_2^{-1},\ \ldots,\ x_nx_n^{-1}\right) = \sum\limits_{\lambda\vdash k} s_\lambda\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\right) s_\lambda\left(x_1^{-1},x_2^{-1},\ldots,x_n^{-1}\right)$. In terms of representations, it means that the $k$-th graded component of $\mathbb{C}\left[\mathfrak{gl}_n\right]$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus\limits_{\lambda\vdash k} S^\lambda \otimes \left(S^\lambda\right)^\ast$.

Comment: Ah, of course! It's just a particular case of the classical decomposition of $\mathbb{C}\left[\mathbb{C}^{n\times m}\right]$ as a $\operatorname{GL}_n\times \operatorname{GL}_m$-module (Howe duality or whatever it's called). This should be in Procesi's book, for example.